# How do I use ZModem in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, zmodem

Is it possible to configure `vs code` to support the `ZMODEM` protocol? I could use `xshell` to download files with `sz` command, but when I try to use `sz` in `vs code`, here it returns some random number.

```
(base) [alpha@hpc03 newfile]$ sz INCAR
�*B00000000000000
```

I use `Remote-SSH` extension in `vs code` to connect to the Linux system.
My question is:
Is there any extension or configuration method that would allow me to use `sz` in `vs code`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (I looked, didn't find anything) there's no existing extension or method to use the ZModem protocol with VSCode. However, there's a [pull request](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/pull/1076) from 2017 that adds support for it to Xterm, which is the terminal display VSCode uses. As indicated in [this mentioning issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/38019) the VSCode developers would need more information.

As far as an extension goes, if you or anyone reading this wanted to make an extension for this purpose, you could use this [ZModem.js](https://github.com/FGasper/zmodemjs) implementation of the protocol in Javascript, and write the extension yourself, or do something similar.

Comment: The mentioning issue sounds like the developer is very open to improvements. It was closed only because there was no further feedback after one week. So maybe open another one with detailed problem description an determination to interact for some days.

Answer (score 0):

From the `Remote-SSH` [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_installing-a-supported-ssh-client)

> VS Code will look for the `ssh` command in the PATH. Failing that, on Windows it will attempt to find `ssh.exe` in the default Git for Windows install path. You can also specifically tell VS Code where to find the SSH client by adding the `remote.SSH.path` property to `settings.json`.

Maybe you can include Xshell somehow this way. Or find a windows version of [zssh](http://zssh.sourceforge.net/) (not [this](https://github.com/openziti-test-kitchen/zssh/releases) from the Ziti project) and it could work. Another candidate is [SecureCRT](https://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/index.html). ([via](https://programmer.group/file-transfer-between-windows-and-linux-rz-sz.html)). Probably these rich GUI apps are not embeddable as simple CLI programs, though. Which would be a useful feature in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Someone submit the issue asking for using szrz in vscode-remote, but upvotes < 10 and not been received and we can restart issue

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6690

Comment: Now a feature request or so called '[backlog candidate](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/milestone/12)' requires 20 upvotes to be accepted into the [backlog](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/milestone/4). See the VSCode [triaging flow](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Issues-Triaging#our-triaging-flow).